# Neo4j store upgrade error

Tags: java, neo4j

I have created a large graph using the Neo4j's 2.2M02 import tool.
Now I want to use the same database in embedded version in 2.2RC01. I get the following error in Java, when I initialize the database:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase, D:\Neo4j\data\test3.db
    at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:331)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase.<init>(EmbeddedGraphDatabase.java:59)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory.newDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:103)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory$1.newDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:90)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseBuilder.newGraphDatabase(GraphDatabaseBuilder.java:176)
    at RCNeo4j.initDB(RCNeo4j.java:419)
    at RCNeo4j.main(RCNeo4j.java:46)
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.state.DataSourceManager@2c7e0aa0' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:513)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:115)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:326)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.NeoStoreDataSource@37b86b14' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:513)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:115)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.state.DataSourceManager.start(DataSourceManager.java:117)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:507)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storemigration.StoreUpgrader$UnexpectedUpgradingStoreVersionException: 'neostore.nodestore.db' has a store version number that we cannot upgrade from. Expected 'v0.A.3' but file is version 'NodeStore v0.A.4'.
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storemigration.UpgradableDatabase.checkUpgradeable(UpgradableDatabase.java:88)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storemigration.StoreMigrator.needsMigration(StoreMigrator.java:157)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storemigration.StoreUpgrader.getParticipantsEagerToMigrate(StoreUpgrader.java:259)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storemigration.StoreUpgrader.migrateIfNeeded(StoreUpgrader.java:134)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.NeoStoreDataSource.upgradeStore(NeoStoreDataSource.java:562)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.NeoStoreDataSource.start(NeoStoreDataSource.java:471)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:507)
    ... 11 more
```

message.log inside the database doesn't seem to show any exception either. I get the same error when I try to move from 2.1.7 to RC01.

Also, on a different note I would also like to know if  it's possible to use the database generated from 2.2M02 in 2.1.7 (kind of like a downgrade). Because I prefer to have a more stable version to do some analysis.

Comment: You will have to reimport your files, which should be fast enough anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Neo4j does not provide an upgrade path between milestone releases, so there is no direct way to upgrade 2.2.0-M02 to 2.2.0-RC1. Upgrades are only supported from one stable to another stable version. Downgrades are not supported at all in the product.

However there is a potential way to do it. Use Michael's store-utils (https://github.com/jexp/store-utils) and change the code using classloader separation in a way that the store you're reading from and the one you're writing to are using separate classloaders with different Neo4j versions.